# Compiling with Delphi 11 gives an error saying it can't find the unit "System"

Tags: delphi

My windows VCL apps won't compile. I am getting the following error:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] xeroexample.dpr(1): F1027 Unit not found: 'System' or binary equivalents (.dcu)

I'm assuming it has something to do with my library path.
Delphi is installed into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin"

I am using Embarcadero RAD Studio 11 Version 28.0.46141.0937, Delphi 11 Update 2, RAD Studio 11.2 Patch 1

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: What does your library path look like? Can you provide exact steps to reproduce the error?

Comment: Also check project options -> Build -> Delphi-Compiler, then Unit scope names. The entries in the target "all platforms" should contain ``System`` besides some others.

Comment: My Library path is : 
$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release;$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports;$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports\$(Platform);$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp;$(BDS)\include;$(DXVCL)\Library\RS28;C:\T\HtmlEditor...

Comment: My Unit Scope names is : Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell

Comment: The Library path contains more paths, but they are all third party components. The total length of the library path is 4602 characters.     


To reproduce the error, I only need to compile an existing or new VCL project.

Comment: What's the value of $BDSLIB (look in "Tools|Options|Environment Variables").  It should be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\lib".   The System.dcu unit should  be in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\lib\win32\Release".  If not, you have a broken installation.

Comment: The value of my $BDSLIB environment variable is exactly what you say it should be, and the system.dcu file is in the correct folder (along with a lot of other system.xxx.dcu files).